# Opencart <title> tag do not show site name on new controller

Tags: php, opencart

I've created a new controller along with new template and language model to display custom registration page for new user

The problem is that the page title for new controller is not displaying site name. For example opencart default registration page title would be "Register Account - [SITE_NAME]" but my new controller displays only "Register User" without the site name

Sure that I can just place site name on language model but that doesn't feel right

I've tried to trace the problem using FirePHP on setTitle function of document class, like this:

```
public function setTitle($title) {
global $firephp;
$firephp->log($title, 'c:document');        
$this->title = $title;
}
```

But I'm still unable to solve the problem.
Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are wanting to add the site name to the store's titles site wide, there's  a simple little trick you can employ to get this done. Open `system/library/document.php` and find the following code

```
$this->title = $title;
```

After this line, put

```
global $config;
if($this->title != $config->get('config_title')) $this->title .= ' - ' . $config->get('config_title');
```

This will make all title's have `Page Title - Site Name` except for pages where the title is simply the `Site name`

Comment: Yep, that's right. But how is it possible he had the site name present at the `Register Account` page? It sounds like a nonsense to me...

Comment: The only way I could see it happening is if the language file had that for specific pages, or there was a vQmod present that alters certain page titles

Comment: make sense since I use vqmod, I'm going to disable vqmod first and report back

Comment: darn it! after disabling some vqmod script now I'm sure that site title is added by the patch and since the new controller is not included in the patch the title is not modified. case closed. thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

From all the code I have checked I am almost sure that the site name is not added to the document title (except the homepage)...

So if You see a site name in the title at `Register Account` page, it is kinda strange...
The controllers have code like

```
$this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));
```

This mean - only the string that is present in the language file is set as the page title.

Also, from the `Document` class:

```
public function setTitle($title) {
    $this->title = $title;
}

public function getTitle() {
    return $this->title;
}
```

means that only what comes to the `Document` class is the returned back, no site name is added anywhere...

What OC version are You using? What browser are You viewing Your site through? This could also be a browser thing...